# Excel throws HRESULT: 0x800A03EC exception when using Range

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

**Hello guys!** I'm really new to Visual Basic and Excel so i don't know if there's a better way to do what i'm trying to do, but this is not important.

I'm trying to set the range for formatting my excel cells with some borders and stuff like that. I don't know how to find the last used cell so i came up with this.

```
range = "A1:AD1"
For Each dataRow In dataTable.Rows
    rowIndex += 1
Next
```

I created the excel sheet from my *data table* so they have the same columns and rows. My *range* was calculated earlier and it depends of how many columns i have in my excel sheet (data table/excel columns could change depending on user input)

after counting every rows in my data table i did this:

```
range = range.Substring(0, range.Length() - 1) & Convert.ToString(rowIndex)
```

The result of last line is *"A1:AD413"*. I checked it on my excel and last used cell is exactly *AD413*

Now, when i try to apply my style on my range, excel throws `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`exception and I know that is something like *"Out of range exception"*. Why excel is throwing it? how can I fix it? The range isn't wrong!

**Line where excel throws exception**

```
wSheet.Cells(range).VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
```

**My code**

```
rowIndex = 0
For Each dr In dt.Rows
    rowIndex += 1
Next

range = range.Substring(0, range.Length() - 1) & Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1)

wSheet.Cells(range).VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
wSheet.Cells(range).HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft
wSheet.Cells(range).Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Comment: If you are trying to find the range of the cells you wrote to, excel worksheets have a property called UsedRange() that will give you all the cells with values inside them, i.e. `wSheet.UsedRange.VerticalAlignment = ...`. As for why you're getting the error, have you checked what value is in `range`? I'd be curious to know what string its holding before the next few lines try to use it

Comment: The `Cells` property takes an (rowNumber, columnNumber) argument as in Cells(1,1) not Cells("A1:B2").  Use the `Range` property on the `wSheet` object.

Comment: @TnTinMn `Cells(range)` worked perfectly before modifying the `range` string to `"A1:AD413"`

Comment: @soohoonigan `range` was holding the string `"A1:AD1`" before `range = range.Substring(0, range.Length() - 1) & Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1)`

Comment: @soohoonigan solved using UsedRange btw. But the enigma is still on :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells() takes two integer parameters for row and column, or a string parameter for a single cell address. If you want to target a range, you need to use Worksheet.Range instead of Worksheet.Cells. Worksheet.Range can accept a starting and ending cell address, such as:

```
wSheet.Range("A1", "AD413").Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

In your case, since you already have the string "A1:AD413" in a variable called range, you could just change the cell-formatting lines to:

```
wSheet.Range(range.Split(":")(0), range.Split(":")(1)).Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Comment: I was pretty sure `wSheet.Cells(range)` worked fine. Probably i was remembering  wrong. Thanks for your help. it works!