# win32com .Formula = "" function wont work?

Tags: winapi, pywin32, win32com

*I only have access to a few Libs at the moment and it is used inside Alteryx. One of these is the Win32Com.*

I have been trying to just copy formulas from a book with the same structure into a new book with the same structure. I can not figure that out--so now i am just trying to write over the cells using Win32Com.formula = "" function

*I can do other things like write "Hello World" or move sheets between books with the tool.*

below is an example of my code that should write the formulas into the sheet, but it is returning an error.

Can anyone with expierience let me know why I am getting these errors?

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True

wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\testing\Test Env\Testing50.xlsx") #Tried without the r as well

ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)

ws2.Cells(10,3).Formula = "=SUMIFS('A-2 Summary Table'!F:F,'A-2 Summary Table'!A:A,'Total','A-2 Summary Table'!B:B,'A','A-2 Summary Table'!C:C,'P','A-2 Summary Table'!D:D,'DM')"

wb2.Close(SaveChanges=True)

xl.Quit()
```

Error:
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      9 ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)
     10 
---> 11 ws2.Cells(10,3).Formula = r"=SUMIFS('A-2 Summary Table'!F:F,'A-2 Summary Table'!A:A,'Total','A-2 Summary Table'!B:B,'Additional 263A','A-2 Summary Table'!C:C,'Pre-Production','A-2 Summary Table'!D:D,'Direct Material')"
     12 
     13 wb2.Close(SaveChanges=True)

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\pythontool_venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py in **setattr**(self, attr, value)
    480                 except KeyError:
    481                         raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
--> 482                 self.*oleobj*.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
    483         def _get_good_single_object_(self, obj, obUserName=None, resultCLSID=None):
    484                 return _get_good_single_object_(obj, obUserName, resultCLSID)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: Your formula is not formatted correctly.  If you plug it directly into Excel on any given cell, an error dialog box comes up.  You may not have the right syntax for SUMIFS

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49794573/1889329) might be related. To diagnose COM issues, you should always convert the error codes to hexadecimal. `-2147352567` is equal to `0x80020009` (`DISP_E_EXCEPTION`). `-2146827284` is `0x800A03EC`.

Comment: The Formula references sheets that have the same name in both. When you test the formula it wont pull because those sheets are not in the wb.

Comment: So I found that the problem is the "=" before the formula. ws2.Cells(10,3).Value = "=Sumifs()" Errors only when I Leave the equals in. Unless, do you think the sumifs is compatible? maybe it is unrecognizable.